# The data types float and int are incompatible in the modulo operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, modulo, sql-server-2019

I can do this:

```
SELECT CAST(1.21 * 100 % 100 AS int)
```

to get the part after the decimal point.

But it won't let me do this:

```
DECLARE @f float;
SET @f = 1.21;
SELECT CAST(@f * 100 % 100 AS int)
```

I get the following error:

> The data types float and int are incompatible in the modulo operator

What am I missing here?

Comment: Nothing, the error tells you the problem. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expands on it: *"dividend/divisor must be a valid expression of any one of the data types in the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data type."* `float` does not fulfil that requirement. Why are you using `float` in the first place? There are very few reasons to be using a base 2 value.

Comment: ^ why are you using float? `DECLARE @f decimal(10,4);` <--- problem solved